# Javascript get name of array field header name

Tags: javascript, json

Im looking for help how to get name of JSON field into array in javascript?
FROM:

```
1: {**BISTRO prodejna**: "0.070327", SUROVINY: "13.858300", **ZBOŽÍ**: "0.000000", KUCHYŇ: "21.924132", PEKÁRNA: "1.097295", …}
2: {BISTRO prodejna: "0.058956", SUROVINY: "3.443841", ZBOŽÍ: "9.338493", KUCHYŇ: "21.236607", PEKÁRNA: "1.093979", …}
```

INTO:

```
for (var i in dataSlozeniTrzeb) {
                       marksSlozeniTrzeb.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i].**BISTRO prodejna**);
                       marksSlozeniTrzeb2.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i].**ZBOŽÍ**);
                   }
```

The names of "columns" are dynamically changed...

Thanks to all help and have a good day. Milan

Comment: Do you **need** to get the name of the field or just iterate over the fields of the object? In the second case, you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

you can use bracket notation to access property

`marksSlozeniTrzeb.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i][**BISTRO prodejna**])`
`marksSlozeniTrzeb2.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i][**ZBOŽÍ**])`

Answer (score 0):

First. You have a malformed JSON.

Correct JSON looks like this:

```
{"BISTRO prodejna": "0.058956", "SUROVINY": "3.443841", "ZBOŽÍ": "9.338493", "KUCHYŇ": "21.236607", "PEKÁRNA": "1.093979", ...}
```

So keys goes wrapped with quotes.

Since you never know your fields names put them into brackets:

```
for (var i in dataSlozeniTrzeb) {
  marksSlozeniTrzeb.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i]);  // i will be "BISTRO prodejna"
  marksSlozeniTrzeb2.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i]); // in first pass
}
```

But if you having it as array (means 1 and 2 in your question are index numbers of a row):

```
[
  {"**BISTRO prodejna**": "0.070327", "SUROVINY": "13.858300", "**ZBOŽÍ**": "0.000000", "KUCHYŇ": "21.924132", "PEKÁRNA": "1.097295", …},
  {"BISTRO prodejna": "0.058956", "SUROVINY": "3.443841", "ZBOŽÍ": "9.338493", "KUCHYŇ": "21.236607", "PEKÁRNA": "1.093979", …}
]
```

Then you can walk with 2 FORs:

```
for (var i in dataSlozeniTrzeb) {
  for (var j in dataSlozeniTrzeb[i]) {
    marksSlozeniTrzeb.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i]);
    marksSlozeniTrzeb2.push(dataSlozeniTrzeb[i]);
  }
}
```